# Web API routing constraint Patch missing in HttpMethod

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am building some restful api using .net Web API V1.

We are trying to define some routing for the web api. I am having some issue in defining the route for 'Put' and 'patch'.

They have the same URL and the only different is in the HttpMethod. In the HttpMethod, there is no support for Patch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod(v=vs.118).aspx

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "UpdateCustomer",
    "api/customers/id/{id}",
    new {controller = "Customers", action = "UpdateCustomer"},
    new {id = @"\d+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put)}
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "PatchCustomer",
    "api/customers/id/{id}",
     new {controller = "Customers", action = "PatchCustomer"},
     new {id = @"\d+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.**Patch**)}
);
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

EDIT: Update to the latest version of WebAPI currently 5.2.7 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/)

ORIGINAL:

If you cannot use instead:

`new HttpMethod("PATCH")`

See the following example use in Web API source code

https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpPatchAttribute.cs

Comment: You should really move to at least Web API 2.23 at this point (if you can)

Comment: Link broken. PATCH has been added as a property in .NET Core starting at 2.1 but still does not appear to be available as a property in Standard nor Framework. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpmethod.patch?view=netcore-2.2#System_Net_Http_HttpMethod_Patch]

Comment: Elsa - Why are you still using WebAPI 1.0? This is now ancient software :). Updated the broken link

Comment: Thank you for updating the link to latest version. WebAPi 1.0 documentation & questions are still relevant for working on legacy system - as you say above "if you can".